# how to pivot dataframe to yield results by department and sum value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot

Is there a way to pivot following dataframe to get the results by departments and total opened days with sum.

```
    Department      2012    2013    2014    
0   Electronics     0       270     365        
1   Electronics     0       0       0           
2   Grocery         242     365     365        
3   Grocery         241     365     365
```

Expected:

```
    Department     Year    Total     
0   Electronics    2012    0         
1   Electronics    2013    270
2   Electronics    2014    365
2   Grocery        2012    483
2   Grocery        2013    730
2   Grocery        2014    730
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do `groupby` with `sum` then `stack`

```
s=df.groupby('Department').sum().stack().to_frame('Total').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the data, [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `Department` and `Year` and [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) to get our total :

```
(df.melt("Department", 
          var_name="Year", 
          value_name="Total")
.groupby(["Department","Year"])
.sum()
 )
                   Total
Department  Year    
Electronics 2012    0
            2013    270
            2014    365
Grocery     2012    483
            2013    730
            2014    730
```